# Do I need additional drivers for Lenovo IdeaPad Z510?

Tags: drivers, 12.04, lenovo

I have a [Lenovo IdeaPad Z510](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/z-series/z510/#techspecs) laptop.

When I open **Additional Drivers** and search for drivers, I can't find any drivers listed there.

Is this because I don't need any additional drivers for my laptop or do I need to download additional drivers for my laptop from a third party software source?

Comment: Important part missing is: what is the videocard in that system? If not nVidia and not AMD (ie. Intel) there is no need for additional drivers.

Comment: It looks like you have Intel graphics. Unless you have a problem you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Lenovo Z510 Tech Specs](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/z-series/z510/#techspecs) your laptop has either the Intel HD 4000 Graphics or the Intel HD 4600 Graphics. Both of them use the built-in graphics drivers that are included in the Ubuntu installation media. There have been some questions on Ask Ubuntu about [problems with the Intel HD 4000 Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Intel+HD+4000+Graphics) on older releases of Ubuntu. If this happens to you, you should consider installing the latest version of Ubuntu. The next Long Term Support version of Ubuntu is Ubuntu 14.04 (which was released in April 14.04 and will be supported by updates until April 2019).