# Does Lenovo ideapad series support Ubuntu y510/z510/u510

Tags: nvidia, lenovo

I am going to buy a new laptop and I need it with nvidia graphics card .. I searched and I found lenovo ideapad series z/y/u 510 have my suitable hardware specs but I cannot find any resources about supporting any of them to Ubuntu and the official site of Lenovo doesn't have any support for lenovo.

My question is :
Does any of those three laptops (y510, z510, u510) support Ubunut ? 
if no . what laptop with Gforce gpu do you recommend to me ?
if yes where to find a guide to install it along side windows?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check http://www.thinkwiki.org it's _the_ site for lenovo (thinkpads originally) and Linux.

Comment: actually it's only about thinkpads which I cannot afford :D .. I am asking about ideapads specifically

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware recommendations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't find the software drivers from Additional Drivers for Lenovo IdeaPad Z510](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425374/i-cant-find-the-software-drivers-from-additional-drivers-for-lenovo-ideapad-z51)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AU! The Lenovo support site does have over 100 documents mentioning Linux [here.](http://mobilesupport.lenovo.com/us/en/search?query=Linux)  A number of Ideapads show up on the first page.